# 手順を記録するウェブアプリを作るとしたら、どんなフレームワークが良いでしょうか。

Tags: php

将棋のような複数のコマが動くようなボードゲームの手順を記録して見返せるようなウェブアプリを作りたいと思っています。phpの経験が少しあるので出来ればphpで作りたいのですが、どのフレームワークが適しているのか判断が付きません。
上記の要件に適したフレームワークがあれば教えてください。

Comment: 将棋や囲碁の UI はスタンドアローンで動いてなんぼだったりするので、オイラなら Web アプリで構成することはあり得ないです。ご検討を。

Comment: 手順というのは単純に棋譜が残すことができればOKですか？それとも盤面を表示してそれらを手順通り再生したり逆再生したりする必要がありますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。    
774RR さんテレビであるような盤面解説をWebアプリで作るイメージでルールなどのロジックは実装しない想定なんですがやはり現実的ではないでしょうか。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん挙げていただいた後者の想定が近いです。  

> それとも盤面を表示してそれらを手順通り再生したり逆再生したりする  
上記にも記載しましたが、将棋や囲碁でテレビの盤面解説するようなことがウェブで出来るようなイメージです。  
盤面と駒があって自由に動かせて、指定の手番を記録出来るような機能を想定しています。

Comment: 検証なし採譜は、通販サイトでクレジットカードの検証なしに決済するみたいなもので（オイラにとっては）非現実的・有害です。逆に盤面解説であればまさに Web アプリで実装するに最適なので、適材適所かと。

Comment: 棋譜を保存したいとなると一手指すごとにサーバ通信をして盤面をレンダリングすることになると思います。しかしながら大盤解説のように、先手の手順だけを説明したり、詰め将棋を披露したりといったルールを無視した対応をしたいとなると、一手指すごとのサーバ通信が邪魔になりますね。棋譜保存とルール無視の自由な盤面はいったん別で考えたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: keitaro_so さん。棋譜作成・保存と解説の２つのモード並行するような機能を実現すると複雑になるということですね。気付かなかったです、ありがとうございます！盤面解説を例に出して複雑な話になってしまいましたが、棋譜保存が主たるwebアプリを作りたいと思います。話を戻してしまいますが今回のような要件に適したまたは実装がしやすいフレームワークはありますでしょうか。